# Login page with JQuery/Bootstrap/Ajax/ColdFusion 16?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, coldfusion

I'm in the process of migrating one of the applications from old system in separate/new system. My Single Page App is built in JQuery/HTML5/CSS/AJAX on the front end and ColdFusion on the back end. Before I start developing my new framework and login page I was hoping for some helpful hints on security and best practice for this purpose. I saw blog post by Raymond Camden where he explained how Login page can be done in JQuery/AJAX and ColdFusion. 
Link: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/03/24/Simple-example-of-a-Form-post-to-ColdFusion-with-jQuery-Login/][1]

He explained the process but I'm wondering about next few things. My main Login page should I use .html file or .cfm file for login page? Also is there any security risk by doing login process through Ajax from submission? I don't have experience in creating Login system and any help would be appreciated. If anyone can provide some useful blogs or code examples that will help in this process please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

I would love to write this as a comment but the question requires a long answer and can be approached many different ways. Please take this with a grain of salt.

Generally, what I have found is the best practices when dealing with any user input especially when the input is being captured in a specific database is the following things:

- Client Side Validation (can be done with JavaScript or HTML5 required attribute, if done correctly can increase security on login form and prevent cross site scripting attacks)
- Server Side Validation (can be done with ColdFusion)
- Using prepared statements **(this is extremely important)** against whatever database you decide to use. This can be done with ColdFusions `<cfquery></cfquery>` tag and make sure to add param for one of the attributes. Documentation is here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html

As for the file, it's subjective because you can have your client side validation on let's say your login page and if they pass client validation, it'll get redirected to a .cfm file that'll perform a server validation. Or you can just have both client side and serverside validation on a single file in which case the file would need to be .cfm

As for your question about the ajax form submission. Yes their are security risks which plays a big role in how you would write your server side validation

When you're performing checks against your database. The most important thing is making sure you sanitize your query inputs whether it be authenticating a user, adding, updating or deleting from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the API manager to do this for you? (it comes free with CF2016 enterprise)

Otherwise lookup the OWASP functions and form security sections of the docs.